# How to override navigator.plugins in javascript or how to set it null?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

`navigator.plugins` in javascript provides the plugins-array for the browser. Is it possible to set this array to null? I tried that(`navigator.plugins = null;`) but it was not setting to null. Also, I tried to set it to an empty array(`navigator.plugins = new Array();`)

Also if this is possible, is this a good practice?

Comment: Why do you want to sent it to null?

Comment: I am working on an iphone app in which I am using a UIWebView as browser. I have to hide the plugin-details for browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome, it is possible to do this by setting `window.navigator` to null. However, I'm not sure why you would do this. Since you're dealing with JavaScript, it would be possible for someone to use a debugger to stop your code from running and intercept this code before you're able to set it to null.

Moreover, the navigator object generally contains information about the client machine, and if I'm the user, I most likely know more about my computer than your server does, so disabling this wouldn't really have any measurable advantage that I can see.

Also, this would have to happen on every pageload.

Finally, I don't know how other browsers would handle this, but you very well may run into trouble trying to do this in other browsers.

In short, I don't think it's a good practice; however, you didn't provide details on why you want to do this. Without that information, I cannot give you a fair answer other than it's not a good idea. So you'll of course need to examine why you want to do this and determine if it's really worth the hassle.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I am working on an iphone app in which I am using a UIWebView as browser. I have to hide the plugin-details for browser. I do not want to set navigator to null but only the plugins array to null. Is that possible in javascript?

Comment: I still don't get why you have to hide the plugin-details. I did try setting only the plugins to null. It doesn't seem possible. Best of luck!

Comment: Perhaps I lack the understanding necessary to grasp what you're trying to do, but aren't you just hiding those details from yourself? Can't every other iPhone app out there still detect and store the device info? If you don't want to read the device info, don't read it. I fail to understand the point of hiding something only from yourself. Again, maybe this is just me...

Comment: "window.navigator=null" does not appear to work anymore for the Desktop version of Chrome today, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There are some web applications which first retrieve browser name.
The navigator object of UIWebView does not return enough information.
for e.g. navigator.userAgent returns

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13C75

These web applications failed to detect browser name from above information and throw exceptions *unsupported browser.*

To handle such situation I override navigator object as given below and yes the web application was able to run perfectly.
This is failed in firefox but my requirement was to support UIWebView only

```
var __originalNavigator = navigator;
navigator = new Object();
navigator.__proto__ = __originalNavigator;
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () { return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"; });
navigator.__defineGetter__('plugins', function () { return []; });
```

Answer (score -3):

I have never heard of anyone wanting to set the plugins array to null, and quite frankly I don't understand what benefit it would yield if you did so. Like jmort253 said, it is possible to set it to null in chrome, but in other browsers you may not be able to. Keep in mind though that navigator.plugin is not a JavaScript array but a pluginArray