# How to override navigator.plugins in javascript?

Tags: javascript, plugins, overriding

How to override navigator.plugins in javascript?
There is a web site that reads my plugins list using with **navigator.plugins** and i don't want let them read my plugins and i want to show them fake plugins list.
How can i do that?

I know this is duplicate, but i'm not satisfied with this one :
[How to override navigator.plugins in javascript or how to set it null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083542/how-to-override-navigator-plugins-in-javascript-or-how-to-set-it-null)

For override a function in javascript we can act like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.DoStuff = function () {
        alert("bar");   //this is the override
    };

    function DoStuff() {
        alert("foo");   //this is the original, occuring later in the page
    };
</script>
```

But what about **navigator.plugins**?
Here is the way we read those plugins list :

```
if (navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins.length) {
    for (var v = "", w = 0; w < navigator.plugins.length; w++) {
        var x = navigator.plugins[w].name; -1 != x.indexOf("Java") && (t = !0);
        v += x + "\r\n"
    }
 alert(v);
}
```

As you see that web site is a malicious web site and want to know installed plugins for some reasons.
How can i bypass them?

---

**Edit base on first answer :**
So how can we change their codes with a js function and replace new plugins list with main list?
In this way there is no need to change read-only **window.navigator.plugins**!

Comment: The `Window.navigator` property is read-only, so you'd think `Window.navigator.plugins` is as well, and that probably means you can't change it.

Comment: how can i override their js codes? mean run a js function to replace main plugins list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Navigator), the `Window.navigator.plugins` property is read-only, and that probably means you can't change it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Navigator

Comment: Thats actually not true, you can change/overwrite every read-only value as long it is configurable via the Object.defineProperty() function.

Comment: @Robbendebiene - native objects like `plugins`, which returns an object of type `pluginsArray` don't even return a PropertyDescriptor, and are read-only, and can't be changed, not even with `defineProperty`, that only works with non-native objects.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wtdvfy3n/1/ I'm also able to add properties with the same method to the navigator.plugins object

Comment: @Robbendebiene - sure, if you just blatantly overwrite the entire object with another one, it doesn't matter if it's read-only as you've just replaced it.

Comment: That is what I call overriding or changing a property, which was ask  by the questioner and declared as impossible by you, but maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Robbendebiene - not really, the OP is trying to change one of the values *inside* `navigator.plugins`, which can't be done as that property is read-only, not just replace the entire list of plugins with something else.

Comment: @Robbendebiene, any idea how to do this via `desiredCapabilities.chromeOptions.args`?